# 'Float' and 'str' objects are not callable

Tags: python

I have a class called Circle, that constructs a circle with a given name and radius. I was given a set of assertions to pass put I get a TypeError:'str' object is not callable and TypeError:'float' object is not callable for methods name() and radius().

```
import math


class Circle:

def __init__(self, name: str, radius: float = 5):
    pass  # TODO
    self.radius = radius
    self.name = name

def radius(self) -> float:
    """
    Returns the radius of this Circle.
    """
    pass  # TODO
    return float(self.radius)

def size(self) -> float:
    """
    Returns the size of this Circle, i.e. the area of the circle.
    """
    pass  # TODO
    size_area = math.pi * pow(self.radius, 2)
    return round(size_area, 3)

def name(self):
    """
    Returns the name of this Circle.
    """
    pass  # TODO
    return str(self.name)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test1 = Circle('Mike', 10)
    assert test1.name() == 'Mike'
    assert test1.radius() == 10
    assert test1.size() == 314.159
```

Comment: So don't overwrite the methods with numbers?

Comment: Having both a data member `name`and a method called `name()` that shadows it to return its string representation seems both overkill and not at all Pythonic. This ain't Java. We just refer to `str(self.name)` (or use `self.name` in a context where it gets implicitly converted to string, like `print`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply add _ before the instance variable like this

```
import math


class Circle:

    def __init__(self, name: str, radius: float = 5):
        pass  # TODO
        self._radius = radius
        self._name = name

    def radius(self) -> float:
        """
        Returns the radius of this Circle.
        """
        pass  # TODO
        return float(self._radius)

    def size(self) -> float:
        """
        Returns the size of this Circle, i.e. the area of the circle.
        """
        pass  # TODO
        size_area = math.pi * pow(self._radius, 2)
        return round(size_area, 3)

    def name(self):
        """
        Returns the name of this Circle.
        """
        pass  # TODO
        return str(self._name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test1 = Circle('Mike', 10)
    assert test1.name() == 'Mike'
    assert test1.radius() == 10
    assert test1.size() == 314.159
```